# Display buttons in JComboBox items

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I currently have a JComboBox which I'm using as an audio playlist - what I'd like to achieve is a little "remove" button on the right hand side of each item that I can use to remove it from the underlying model, where the circle is:

What would be the best way of achieving this?

I'd like the button to be the same for all items in the JComboBox.

[image: demo screenshot]

Comment: are you want to `1)` put JLabel and with JButton to the one Item, `2)` for all Items in the JComboBox or not

Comment: @mKorbel Not sure what you mean by your first point? But for the second point, yes.

Comment: there I see one important issue, JComboBox drop_down go away after any Mouse_click to the Item (Java1.4 and higher), are you agree and accepting that

Comment: Why not a `JList` and a `Remove selected` button?

Comment: @trashgod I may be missing something obvious - but is there an easy way to get a JList to appear in a drop down format like with a JComboBox?

Comment: No; I meant using a `JList` as a playlist editor, perhaps as an adjunct to the combo. `JComboBox` isn't really designed for that; an editable playlist may deserve its own composite component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Let me start by saying that this is an interesting question (+1 a while ago).*

I had to quickly try and see for myself how difficult it is to achieve the wanted result with `JComboBox`. The conclusion I got (as @trashgod says in the comment above) was that this object was never designed to have other components or at least it feels like this to me.

Below is a sample that does something what you want. You could use it as a start, but to be honest you should forget about using the `JComboBox` for this problem.

**For no means the sample below presents the right way of approaching the problem. It simply shows the result of my attempts of approaching the problem. The code below doesn't preserve good practice rules e.g. it mixes presentation with functionality (the renderer removes the elements). This is in fact just a hack not a real solution.**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ButtonCombo {

    private JPanel getContent() throws MalformedURLException {
        String[] ids = {"north", "west", "south", "east"};
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(ids);
        Icon removeIcon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://filesharefreak.org/images/red_x.png"));
        combo.setRenderer(new ButtonComboRenderer(removeIcon, combo));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(combo);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                    panel.add(new ButtonCombo().getContent());
                    JButton button = new JButton("OKOKO");
                    panel.add(button);
                    f.setContentPane(panel);
                    f.setSize(300, 160);
                    f.setLocation(200, 200);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ButtonCombo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class ButtonComboRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {
    Icon icon;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;
    JButton button;

    public ButtonComboRenderer(Icon removeIcon, final JComboBox combo) {
        icon = removeIcon;
        label = new JLabel();
        button = new JButton(icon);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight()));
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (button.getX() < e.getX()) {
                    System.out.println("button contains the click remove the item");
                    combo.removeItem(label.getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //so we will install the mouse listener once
    boolean isFirst = true;

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
            Object value,
            int index,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (isFirst) {
            isFirst = false;
            list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    panel.dispatchEvent(e);
                    e.consume();
                }
            });
        }
        String text = (String) value;
        label.setText(text);
        if(text == null)
            button.setIcon(null);
        else if(button.getIcon() == null)
            button.setIcon(icon);
        panel.setBackground(isSelected ? Color.red : Color.white);
        panel.setForeground(isSelected ? Color.white : Color.black);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

---

My final recommendation and the way I would do it is:
**BUILD YOUR OWN COMPONENT.** Make it extensible and modifiable by separating it from the trigger and presentation, where both use `JComponent`s as they come as oppose to using a renderer. In this way you would be able to capture and serve events on the components rather than as in this case all events are captured by the `JList` used for rendering.

Below is a sample that should help you start. It is not the final solution but it presents lots of the important issues involved in making such component. You should use the presented functionality and wrap it all accordingly in a single component:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MockJComboBox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JPanel popupContent = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                popupContent.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                popupContent.add(new JLabel("Content of popupContent panel"));
                popupContent.add(new JLabel("Content of popupContent panel"));
                popupContent.add(new JLabel("Content of popupContent panel"));
                popupContent.add(new JLabel("Content of popupContent panel"));
                popupContent.add(new JLabel("Content of popupContent panel"));
                popupContent.add(new JComboBox(new Object[]{"Content of popupContent panel"}));
                final JButton popupCloseButton = new JButton("X");
                popupContent.add(popupCloseButton);

                final JScrollPane s = new JScrollPane(popupContent);
                s.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(popupContent.getPreferredSize().width + s.getVerticalScrollBar().getPreferredSize().width
                        + s.getBorder().getBorderInsets(s).left
                        + s.getBorder().getBorderInsets(s).right, 100));

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
                final JButton popupOpenButton = new JButton();
                panel.add(popupOpenButton);
                final JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(panel);
                final PopupFactory popupFactory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
                popupOpenButton.setAction(new AbstractAction("Open") {
                    private Popup popup;
                    private boolean isShown = false;

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        if (isShown) {
                            popup.hide();
                        } else {
                            popup = popupFactory.getPopup(popupOpenButton, s,
                                    popupOpenButton.getLocationOnScreen().x, popupOpenButton.getLocationOnScreen().y + popupOpenButton.getHeight());
                            popupCloseButton.setAction(new AbstractAction(popupCloseButton.getText()) {

                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    isShown = false;
                                    popup.hide();
                                }
                            });
                            popup.show();
                        }
                        isShown = !isShown;
                    }
                });
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```