# Remove item in JCombobox drop down list on clicking Icon next to it

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to create a jcombobox in which an icon displayed next to each of the listed item within the JComboBox drop-down list – clicking on which will remove that item.
[Example as Image](http://s24.postimg.org/tco1o31g5/Clipboard002.jpg)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display buttons in JComboBox items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065282/display-buttons-in-jcombobox-items)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JComboBox` (and many other Swing components) rely on renderers to provide custom rendering of the values they display.  This makes it easy to provide multiple different views of the same data.

Start by taking a read through [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Pay attention to the section on [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)